How to properly check the username and email availability showing formik's ErrorMessage here
I need to check if the username and email are available. I have routes for these as well.
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ErrorMessage, Form, Formik, Field } from "formik";

import {
  checkEmailAvailability,
  checkUsernameAvailability,
  register,
} from "../api/auth";
import { setCurrentUser, setMessage } from "../state";
import { getErrorMessage } from "../utils/helper";

const initialValues = {
  displayName: "",
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  confirm_password: "",
};

export default function Register() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const usernameErrorMessage = "Username is already used.";
  const emailErrorMessage = "Email address is already used.";

  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const { data } = await register(values);
      localStorage.setItem("chat-token", `Bearer ${data.token}`);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(data.user));
      dispatch(
        setMessage({
          success: true,
          text: "Email verification link was sent to your email address.",
        })
      );
      setIsLoading(false);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        setMessage({
          success: false,
          text: getErrorMessage(error),
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const checkUsername = async (value) => {
    const isAvailable = await checkUsernameAvailability(value);
    console.log("HELLO", isAvailable);
    return isAvailable.data;
  };

  const checkEmail = async (value) => {
    const isAvailable = await checkEmailAvailability(value);
    return isAvailable.data;
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    displayName: Yup.string()
      .required("Display name is required.")
      .min(2, "Display name must be at least 2 characters."),
    username: Yup.string()
      .required("Username is required.")
      .min(2, "Username must be at least 2 characters.")
      .test("check-username-availability", usernameErrorMessage, checkUsername),
    email: Yup.string()
      .required("Email address is required.")
      .email("Invalid email address.")
      .test("check-email-availability", emailErrorMessage, checkEmail),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(6, "Password must contain at least 6 characters.")
      .required("Password is required."),
    confirm_password: Yup.string()
      .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Passwords do not match.")
      .required("Confirm password."),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("chat-token");
    if (token) navigate("/");
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {({ errors }) => (
        <Form className="form">
          <div className="form__group">
            <Field
              className="form__field"
              id="displayName"
              name="displayName"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Display Name"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              className="form__error-message"
              name="displayName"
              component="div"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <Field
              className="form__field"
              id="username"
              name="username"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              className="form__error-message"
              name="username"
              component="div"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <Field
              className="form__field"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email address"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              className="form__error-message"
              name="email"
              component="div"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <Field
              className="form__field"
              id="password"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              className="form__error-message"
              name="password"
              component="div"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <Field
              className="form__field"
              id="confirm_password"
              name="confirm_password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              className="form__error-message"
              name="confirm_password"
              component="div"
            />
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="form__button"
            disabled={Boolean(Object.entries(errors).length)}
          >
            {isLoading ? "Registering..." : "Sign Up"}
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}


I know it's bad, cause it sends a request to the server with every written letter in these fields, but I couldn't find any better solution to this. I also have access to the server, so we can change things there as well.
